# How to use HAVING with COUNT as aggregation function

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to display only genres which have at least two titles.

My Titles table:

```
Titles
------
TitleID, ArtistID, Title, StudioID, Genre
```

My Tracks table:

```
Tracks
------
TitleID, TrackNum, TrackTitle
```

This is my code so far:

```
select t.genre from titles t
join tracks tr
on (tr.titleid = t.titleid)
having count(tr.tracktitle) > 1;
```

I don't this the current code is answering the described question correctly.

Comment: I would have concerns about duplicate rows. Probably need to add a distinct inside the count(). Why don't you think it's correct?

Comment: Do you need the Tracks table in there at all?
It sounds like you only need the Titles table for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use `HAVING` with a real meaning, you should use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT t.genre, count(tr.tracktitle) num_tracktitle
FROM titles t
    JOIN tracks tr
       ON (tr.titleid = t.titleid)
GROUP BY t.genre
HAVING num_tracktitle > 1;
```

Comment: Use `having num_tracktitle > 1` so you don't have to count twice.

Comment: Sidenote: MySQL is optimised enough that it does not count twice.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the tracks table? It seems like you have everything you need in the title table.

```
SELECT
    TI.Genre,
    Count(TI.TitleID) As Titles
FROM
    Titles TI
GROUP BY
    TI.Genre
HAVING
    COUNT(TI.TItleID) > 1
```